# Does some one understand why page_view could not be sent while ad_impressions did?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

When I am try to explore the bouncers in my products from the user explorer report, I saw there are no page_view event was sent but ad_impression events were sents from these bouncers in GA4 Explore report. Does some one understand why page_view could not be sent while ad_impressions did?[the behavior of bouncer like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDuQo.png)

It is grateful if you can share your knowlegde or experience in this problem and how can I fix it